# how to apply last key from a program itself without requiring a user input? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

In some cases I need my program to perform the automatic keys apply from the program itself. I dont want a user to give or press any keys. It should be automatic when it reaches some conditions. I am using below query which requires input from the user. Please help to modify.

```
/*some conditions here..now its not required user input*/
case keyfunction(lastkey):
  when {&KEY-END} then
    undo RPT-SETTING-LOOP, next SOURCE-DB-LOOP.
  when {&KEY-GO} or when {&KEY-RETURN} then
    leave RPT-SETTING-LOOP.
 end case.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using LASTKEY directly use a variable and conditionally set the variable as needed to act accordingly:

```
define variable notLastkey as integer no-undo.

/*some conditions here..now its not required user input*/

if theUserTypedSomethingBranch = yes then
  notLastKey = lastkey.
 else
  notLastKey = whateverYouDesire.

case notLastkey:
  when {&KEY-END} then
    undo RPT-SETTING-LOOP, next SOURCE-DB-LOOP.
  when {&KEY-GO} or when {&KEY-RETURN} then
    leave RPT-SETTING-LOOP.
 end case.
```

Comment: It worked!! @Tom Bascom.. One case its failing..In one condition, the message "Press space to continue " appears in the main screen(menu). I have to press a space bar. How do handle that? How can we apply key function to that message? so that each time it appears then the automatic key apply will handle it

Comment: I'm flying blind not knowing what your code looks like but the simple thing would be to use whatever logic you used to determine that you are in the "userTypedSomething" vs "userDidNOTType" branch to set a variable indicating whether or not to ask for that PAUSE and skip it when you don't need it.

Comment: I agree tom what you are saying is right. But since I have limited knowledge in the progress, I am not able to get it from where the message "Press space to continue" is coming. That's the problem. This message coming automatically during the execution. In this case I am not sure how to handle it. so finally whatever coming automatically to the main screen that key functionality should handle without user input

Comment: Add “pause 0 before hide” to your no user input branch.

Comment: Minor correction, the proper sytax is: "pause 0 before-hide." (I left out the hypen.)